Firestore get() seems to hang randomly
I'm on Flutter-web.
I have a Firestore collection schools and every school has a collection of pupils.  I have about 5000 schools and 500000 pupils.
I want to visit every pupil and wrote
  await visitSchoolPupils(
      onSchoolPupil: (s, school, pupil) async {
        //print("School ${school.schoolName}, pupil ${pupil.userName}");
        return true;
      });

where
  Future<void> visitSchoolPupils({required Future<bool> Function(DocumentSnapshot s, School school, Pupil pupil) onSchoolPupil}) async {
    int start = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    int pupilCtr = 0;
    await visitSchools(
        onSchool: (s, school) async {
          print(">>>DEBUG onSchool ${school.schoolId}");
          try {
            //pick all pupils
            QuerySnapshot pupilSnapshot = await s.reference.collection(keyPupils).get();
            List<Future> pupilTasks = [];
            for (DocumentSnapshot doc in pupilSnapshot.docs) {
              JsonMap pupilData = (doc.data()) as JsonMap;
              Pupil pupil = Pupil.fromJson(pupilData);
              pupilTasks.add(onSchoolPupil(doc, school, pupil));

              // Execute in batches
              if (pupilTasks.length >= 5) {
                await Future.wait(pupilTasks);
                pupilTasks.clear();
              }
            }
            await Future.wait(pupilTasks);
            pupilTasks.clear();
            print("<<<DEBUG onSchool ${school.schoolId}");
            return true;
          } catch (e, trace) {
            print("pupil tasks1 $e $trace");
            return false;
          }
        });
    print("DEBUG visitSchoolPupils: READY took ${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - start} ms for $pupilCtr pupils");
  }

and
Future<void> visitSchools({required Future<bool> Function(DocumentSnapshot s, School school) onSchool}) async {
    int start = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(keySchools).get();
    int ctr=0;
    int nr = snapshot.docs.length;
    print("DEBUG visitSchools: START $nr schools");
    //for all schools
    List<Future> tasks = [];
    for (DocumentSnapshot s in snapshot.docs) {
      JsonMap schoolData = (s.data()) as JsonMap;
      School school = School.fromJson(schoolData);

      ctr++;
      if(ctr%100==0)print("DEBUG[${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - start}] visitSchools[$ctr] ${school.schoolId}");
      tasks.add(onSchool(s, school));

      // Execute in batches of 10 or on final iteration
      if (tasks.length >= 5) {
        await Future.wait(tasks);
        tasks.clear();
      }
    }
    await Future.wait(tasks);
    tasks.clear();
    print("DEBUG visitSchools: READY took ${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - start} ms");
  }

Note that I add 5 futures in a list and use Future.wait to wait for them together (to speed things up)
This code hangs from time to time.  I notice that the 5 onSchool are started but none of them seems to finish.
The code runs fine when I add only a single Future to tasks and pupilTasks.
The problem seems to be random, sometimes I get to 1000 schools, sometimes to 4000.  Is there a "thread-safety" issue that I'm overlooking? Memory that I'm accumulating?  Can Future.wait have issues when some of the futures are already completed?
Any suggestions on how to debug this issue/improve this code?
EDITED: when I run this in debug mode, the application also stops.  It stops as if it hits a breakpoint (no stack trace) but I can resume execution and then it continues fine till the end.

Every time you're loading hundreds or thousands of documents from Firestore in a front-end app, you're doing it wrong.
I recommend treating every document as if it's a separate file. I doubt you'd ever load hundreds of individual files from a server, so you shouldn't load that many documents either.
Instead, consider what information your app actually needs to display from those documents to the user, and only load that data.

For example, you're likely displaying a list of school names. Rather than loading all the school documents to show the names, create a collection where you just the school names - with multiple school names per document with some hashing mechanism.

Next, consider if you really need hundreds or thousands of school names right away. If you're showing them in a list, it likely won't fit more than tens (on mobile) or hundreds (desktop) at a time, so that's all you should load. You can use a count() query to determine how many school names there are (to determine the length of the list), and then use cursor-based pagination to get only the first N names and load the rest on demand.

If you combine the previous two approaches, you can store the names in whatever sort-order you need in the schoolname documents - and then load only one or two of those.


If you're new to NoSQL data modeling, I recommend reading NoSQL data modeling techniques and watching Get to know Cloud Firestore. Spending a few hours on those now, will save you much more time down the line.

Some other (non data modeling) changes to consider:

By calling get() as you do, you're forcing the SDK to get the documents from the server (or at least check there) before it returns anything. Consider using a snapshot() listener to eagerly get the documents from the local cache, while also receiving updates from the server.

Even with your current data model, ensure that local caching is enabled and consider pre-loading school data into that cache with a data bundle.



Thanks for your input and valuable pointers.  I only visit all schools/pupils when I want to add/modify the database, eg add pre-calculate some properties due to an additional UI requirement.   Is this more efficient from the back-end?
Even if my design is bad, the get() shouldn't hang, right?

It all depends on how much data you get. An unconstrained, unlimited get() is always the first place I look, but you'll need to debug it to see exactly when it fails and what the context looks like at that point (memory usage, etc). It's unlikely that anyone will find a/another smoking gun  in the code you shared, which is why I gave data modeling advice.

"Thanks for your input and valuable pointers" -> Also see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers]
